# Rails how to select from joined associations pointing to the same table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

Suppose I have a model **Incident** and **Employee** related by associations:

**Incident**

```
belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'Employee', foreign_key: :recipient_id
belongs_to :responder, class_name: 'Employee', foreign_key: :responder_id
```

I would like to have a scope in Incident model that will retrive among other things *names* of recipient and responder.

```
scope :report, -> {left_joins(:recipient, :responder).select('incidents.*', 'responder.name AS Responder Name', 'recipient.name AS Recipient Name')}
```

I have tried things like this but I have always got the "missing FROM-clause.." errors.

What I need to understand is:

How do I refer to the joined association in select so that I can distingush 
between responder and recipient which are records of the same table but refered to based on different foreing key?

Comment: You don't need to set `foreign_key` on the `belongs_to` side unless it cannot be derived from the name of the association (IE its not name + _id).

Answer (score 3):

You need to alias the table when joining:

```
SELECT 
  incidents.*, 
  recipient.name AS recipient_name, 
  responder.name AS responder_name 
FROM "incidents" 
LEFT JOIN 
  users recipient ON recipient.id = incidents.recipient_id 
LEFT JOIN 
  users responder ON responder.id = incidents.responder_id
```

You also need to use a proper alias for the selected columns - "Recipient Name" does not map well to a ruby method name.

```
class Incident < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User'.freeze
  belongs_to :responder, class_name: 'User'.freeze

  def self.report
    self.select('
      incidents.*,
      recipient.name AS recipient_name,
      responder.name AS responder_name
    ')
        .joins("LEFT JOIN users recipient ON recipient.id = incidents.recipient_id")
        .joins("LEFT JOIN users responder ON responder.id = incidents.responder_id")
  end
end
```

---

```
irb(main):028:0> Incident.report.map(&:attributes)
  Incident Load (1.4ms)  SELECT incidents.*, recipient.name AS recipient_name, responder.name AS responder_name FROM "incidents" LEFT JOIN users recipient ON recipient.id = incidents.recipient_id LEFT JOIN users responder ON responder.id = incidents.responder_id
=> [{"id"=>1, "recipient_id"=>1, "responder_id"=>2, "created_at"=>Thu, 08 Mar 2018 15:51:52 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Thu, 08 Mar 2018 15:51:52 UTC +00:00, "recipient_name"=>"Bob", "responder_name"=>"Erika"}]
```

Comment: I admire your dedication to write that much code and provide such detailed answers with relevant examples. You deserve a +1, like most of the time!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `includes` instead of `joins` and use default getter methods instead of `select`:

```
Incidents.includes(:recipient, :responder).each do |incident|
  puts incident
  puts incident.recipient.name
  puts incident.responder.name
end
```

Comment: That will work but I do not want to load all columns from employees table because of performance requirements..